# How to fetch data from external php page

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch data from an external php page.
The user can see this php page only after he logged in.

So, I want ho reach this aim:
the user logs in and can see page1.php (from an external site). 
Then he opens my page (page2.php) and I should be able to fetch the content of page1.php.
How can I do it?

Comment: Whether this is possible depends highly on how the other site is structured. What you're doing could amount to a CSRF attack and a well constructed site will protect against that behavior or offer a data API to expose authenticated pages.  It also may be prohibited by the other site's terms. We can't help without knowing a lot more details about how the other site's login works.

Comment: But server to server with a user in between, it will likely be hard to do this because you would need to simulate the user's session (as though stealing credentials and probably storing session cookies too) and again, cross site request forgery protections hopefully are in place to prevent that on the other site.

Comment: This is too broad a question; try something then come back when you have trouble with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in the general case, impossible.

To display third party information on your site you need to do one of two things:

- Server side: Have your server fetch the data and then send it to the user
- Client side: Have the browser fetch the data and inject it into the page

You can't do this server side because you need credentials to access the data. The user has credentials, but their browser is only going to send them to the third party site. The browser won't give them to your site.

You can't do this client side, because [the Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) forbids it.

---

Now, if you controlled both sites (or were sufficiently friendly with whomever controls the third party site) then you could use a technology like [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) to get access to the data server side or [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to get access client side. It doesn't sound like that is the case though.

Answer (score -1):

I see you have confused a lot !!! From your question you are saying that you want to send details from page1.php(from external source) to page2.php.

Basically if you want to send data across pages you need to use forms and its the only way ...

In page1.php put all details you want to send in a form. onsumbit of the form direct to page2.php and access the data in page2.php